# It is possible the mask 255.255.231.0 in IPv4?

Tags: networking, mask, ipv4, bitmask

I have a simple question related with networking, Is it possible to have a mask 255.255.231.0 in IPv4? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think so. The mask [should contain all ones followed by all zeros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Determining_the_network_prefix), and 231 is 1110 0111. So the mask would read 11111111.11111111.11100111.00000000.

The valid values are 254, 252, 248, 240, 224, 192, 128 and 0.